Flutter App Crashes When Saving Text File Using File Picker and Permission Handler
I am developing a Flutter app where I need to save a text file to the device's storage. I am using the file_picker package to select the save location and the permission_handler package to request necessary permissions. However, my app crashes when trying to save the file. Interestingly, a file gets created but with 0 bytes. Here are the details:
My Flutter Function
Future<void> saveTextFile() async {
    var storageStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
    var manageStorageStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;

if (kDebugMode) {
 print('::::::::::::: Storage status: $storageStatus');
 print('::::::::::::: Manage storage status: $manageStorageStatus');
}

if (!storageStatus.isGranted) {
storageStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
} 

if (storageStatus.isDenied || storageStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
  manageStorageStatus = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
}

if (storageStatus.isGranted || manageStorageStatus.isGranted) {
  try {
    // Create some lorem ipsum text
    String loremText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
    // Convert the text to bytes
  final bytes = utf8.encode(loremText);
  String fileName = 'LoremIpsum.txt';

  // Open the file picker for the user to choose the save location
  String? outputFile = await FilePicker.platform.saveFile(
    dialogTitle: 'Save your text file',
    fileName: fileName,
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['txt'],
  );

  if (outputFile != null) {
    final file = File(outputFile);
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);

    // Show a message indicating the file has been saved.
    Get.snackbar('Success', 'Lorem ipsum text has been saved as a text file.');
  } else {
    // User canceled the file save dialog
    Get.snackbar('Cancelled', 'File save operation was cancelled.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  // Catch any errors during the file writing process
  Get.snackbar('Error', 'An error occurred while saving the file: $e');
  debugPrint('Error saving file: $e');
 }
} else {
// Handle permission denial
Get.snackbar('Permission Denied', 'Storage permission is required to save the file.');
}

}
AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:label="SJIC Admin"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

Problem Description
When I attempt to save a text file using the provided Flutter function, the app crashes. However, upon checking the files, a file is created but it is 0 bytes in size. Here is the detailed flow and what I have tried so far:

Request Permissions: I request storage permissions using the permission_handler package.
Generate Text Content: I generate some lorem ipsum text and convert it to bytes.
File Picker: I use the file_picker package to allow the user to select the save location.
Save File: I attempt to save the file to the chosen location.

Observations

The file is created but is 0 bytes.
The app crashes without detailed error logs.

What I've Tried
build gradle
       /// .......
       minSdkVersion 30
       targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
   }

Flutter SDK : 3.19.3

path_provider: ^2.1.3
permission_handler: ^11.3.1
file_picker: ^8.0.3


no output in the debug pane at all? Also check the Android device log via Android Studio. In which line does it crash when you step with the debugger?
Have you tried a flutter clean to force a rebuild of everything? Sometimes old build artefacts can make problems

Yes, after spending a lot of time on this code, I found a solution. The reason is that we need to pass "bytes" inside the File picker function. My solution is given below. Thank you for the reply. ❤️❤️❤️

I found the solution to the issue where my Flutter app was crashing when trying to save a text file. The root cause was related to the FilePicker package and the way the file bytes were being handled. Here's the corrected approach:
Problem:
When attempting to save a text file, the app crashes, and although a file gets created, it has 0 bytes. This was due to not passing the bytes parameter correctly within the FilePicker function.
Solution:
The bytes parameter needs to be included directly within the FilePicker.platform.saveFile method to ensure the file data is passed correctly.


which FilerPicker package are you using that actually creates a File and saves it? the file_picker package only returns you the path but doesn't create a file?

@Thomas
file_picker: ^8.0.3 https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Interestingly, they don't have the bytes parameter documented. I would probably do the actual file handling by myself and only use the picker to pick the path.

Yes, brother, that's the case. There is no clue on the whole internet, ChatGPT, or any other AI model. After spending a long time inside the code, I accidentally found this while debugging the app. If you find anything related to this, please reply.

As said, I would not use this function but only use the picker to get the path and do the rest with the functions of the Dart File class

so how do you handle O bytes file?
